# Keyboard misconfigured after resume from suspend-to-ram

Tags: x11, keyboard

I suspend to ram. Sometimes when I resume, some of the keys do not work. Some keys are reacting, but <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> for one is not.

What can I do to ask the auto detection to retry configuring keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to a console (CTRL-ALT-F1) and switch back (CTRL-ALT-F8) solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You should (i) upgrade everything in your distribution (or upgrade if it is out of date/not maintained actively anymore), and (ii) report to them.

At best, here we might suggest workarounds, or speculate on possible bugs. No real solution will be forthcomming.

Comment: Everything is upgraded. I cannot reproduce the bug reliably - it only happens sometimes and only on this one machine. So for all we know it could be due to faulty hardware. All in all it would make for a pretty crappy error report. Therefore a workaround is IMO the best way forward - which is also why I ask for that. I found a workaround - see other answer.